# Running javascript as an ASP server control is rendered

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, servercontrols

What is the preferred approach for running JavaScript right as an ASP server control is rendered on the page.
The documentation is a bit confusing/obtuse.

Comment: Do you mean RegisterStartupScript vs RegisterScriptBlock?

Comment: or simply include `<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello world");</script>` directly in markup (ascx) file.

Comment: Yea, should that work from a server control?

Comment: It's not an ascx file, it's a server control

Comment: But I guess I could just render that come to think of it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation prefers that you use the page's ClientScriptManager to render all javascript. I think this is an effort to get you to consolidate javascript into reusable sections, so that you render the javascript once, no matter how many controls you have.

Your way is going to emit javascript for every control. This isn't necessarily bad (especially if you are the only user of your server control).

Basically, you'll just add the script you need as part of the Render phase of the control, and use the HtmlTextWriter to output it (probably just before you return from the Render override). I find it helpful to have helper classes to assist.